Create Spark DataFrame From List of Tuples
I am working with CIFAR10 data and I created a list of tuples containing the following data. The code I used is the following:
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = datasets.cifar10.load_data() # download CIFAR10 data

X_train = X_train.astype("float32") / 255

X_test = X_test.astype("float32") / 255 # normalize the pixels values to range 0 to 1

X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], -1))

X_test = X_test.reshape((X_test.shape[0], -1)) # convert the 3-dimensional data into a 1-dimensional array keeping the 32*32*3 pixel values

y_train = y_train.flatten()

y_test = y_test.flatten()

Then I define dff as following:
dff = [(float(y), list(x)) for x, y in zip(X_train_flattened, y_train.flatten())]

That contains the data showed below, with len(dff) = 5000.
(6.0, [0.23137255,   0.24313726,   0.24705882,   0.16862746,   0.18039216,   0.1764706,   0.19607843, .....]), 
(9.0, [0.23137255,   0.24313726,   0.24705882,   0.16862746,   0.18039216,   0.1764706,   0.19607843, .....]), 
...

where the first element of the tuple is the label and the second element is the flattened pixel values.
When I run the line:
train_df = spark.createDataFrame(dff, schema = ["label", "features"])

I get the following error:
PySparkTypeError: \[CANNOT_INFER_TYPE_FOR_FIELD\] Unable to infer the type of the field `features`.

where dff is the list of tuples containing the data I described above.
Can you please help me identify what I am doing wrong here or what I am missing?
I am trying to get something like this:
+------------------+------------------+
| Label | Features                    | 
+------------------+------------------+
| 6.0   | 0.23137255, 0.24313726, ... |  
| 9.0   | 0.23137255, 0.24313726, ... |  
...

I tried to convert this to a pandas df and then convert it to a spark df but I ran out of RAM. I am running this in Colab Notebook.
UPDATE
I define the schema explicitly as:
schema = StructType([
StructField("label", FloatType(), False),
StructField("features", ArrayType(FloatType()), False)])

Then I run the line code:
train_df = spark.createDataFrame(dff, schema = schema)

And got this error:
PySparkTypeError: [CANNOT_ACCEPT_OBJECT_IN_TYPE] `FloatType()` can not accept object `0.23137255` in type `float32`.


i'm unable to replicate the issue. your code works perfectly on my setup with the data you provided.

I already update the question with the code I have at this moment.

please elaborate your problem. your code works fine on my colab

Idk why this code doesn't run on my colab notebook. I updated the question with new line codes, but I got a new error.

check the data types within the list

I already fix the code. Thanks a lot!

please mention the fixes made for future reference of other users

For sure, I'll update the fixes I made these days.

Depending on the result you need, the Features field should be of array type.
You need to define dff as a standard list of tuples to create a dataframe.
dff = [
    (6.0, [0.23137255, 0.24313726, 0.24705882, 0.16862746, 0.18039216, 0.1764706, 0.19607843]),
    (9.0, [0.23137255, 0.24313726, 0.24705882, 0.16862746, 0.18039216, 0.1764706, 0.19607843]),
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(dff, schema=['label', 'features'])


I forgot write it, but I already defined dff as the standard list of tuples. Sorry about that.

I already update it.
